# Vishnu and the Buddha relationship

Tags: vishnu

What is the relationship of the Buddha realm(s) with Vishnu? This is not asking about the historical Buddha or his previous incarnations, but about the metaphysical space inhabited by five Tathagatas (diamond realm?).  What if any are the points to consider?
One source of the Buddhist cosmology is located [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/A_Diagrammatic_representation_of_the_Buddhist_Universe.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

If u mean the relation between Vishnu & Buddh, whom Buddhists follow, so, no there is no link amongst duo.
But, the buddh tht was born in Sanatana dharma was the 9th avatar of Vishnu.
As per Bhavishya puran it says abt the birth place of the 9th avatar of Vishnu who righteously Buddh, "कीकाटेषु भविष्यति", meaning the sanatani Buddha will be born in किकट pradesh. As per Shreedhar Swami's commentary, Kikat is none other than Gaya. And moreover, Buddha who was the avatar of Vishnu was born to Brahmin couples, unlike Gautama Buddha who was born in Kshatriya kula.
Gautam buddh was born in Lumbini and got enlightenment at Gaya. While the Buddha revered as avatar was born in Gaya itself.
Whereas the avtar Buddha revived Vedas and vedic kriyas, but on the other hand Gautama criticized Vedas.
So, there r huge differences between the duo. The contemplating verse of the 9th avatar ie Buddha is mentioned in Agni puran, which was adopted by others. And thus,the confusion aroused with time amongst masses

सर्वम श्री कलिकार्पणमस्तु।

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer relies on a single Puran commentary only. The second birth in Hinduism (Dvija: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvija) is when the person takes the role of fulfilling the society, i.e. for brahmins - it is to take the role of studying the nature of brahman. Given the role of buddha - who studied the role of brahman and propagated it, he was not only a perfect brahmin but also took second birth in Kakata Pradesh.